# Weightlessness under free fall?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, reference-frames, free-fall, weight

What are the possible ways of showing that freely falling objects has no weight in normal life and in laboratories?

Comment: At about 35 minutes in this video https://youtu.be/Z07tTuE1mwk

Comment: @PrinceGupta This still appears as a homework like question that doesn't show any of your work or bring up a conceptual difficulty.  It says why it is closed and gives a pretty detailed explanation.